# Having a bunch of global variables or calculate them on the go on an Arduino, as far as memory is concerned

Tags: arduino-mega, variables, memory-usage, memory, performance

So I'm new in the arduino world but I have a grasp of object oriented programming, and decided to write a little library for running games on an arduino mega using a display. My question is, I'm creating an "Entity" class (to spawn multiple enemies, players, etc) outside the setup() and the loop() functions, so they dont overwrite themselfs when the program is running (don't know if there's a better way), and I want to store position information, like xPos and yPos, but I need to calculate a lot of other stuff based on those two variables, and creating more variables makes the code more easy to read/write.

But I don't know how this would affect the memory usage or speed, because I ran into some problems earlier when I tried to create a big array, it end up using like 300% of the dynamic memory, so I guess that when I declare a global byte, for example, the arduino allocates the whole memory as if you would use the biggest byte possible.

Sorry for bad english :s

Comment: Maybe try to change some constant variables to #define values, because they need nearly no storage. Also a ESP32 has 4MB of flash, with that much more place (the Mega has 256KB) place shouldn't be a problem anymore.

Comment: Well, I want to know if should I avoid creating more variables that I know they can be calculated easily, but makes the code more readable, or if I just stick to the most basic variables.

Comment: Thanks @PythonSchlange, I'll keep that in mind, I never understood the use of #define till now.

Comment: On an Arduino Mega, the “biggest byte possible” is 8-bits wide.

Comment: @EdgarBonet, yeah, but I was trying to calculate collisiones just using a 2d array, like simulating every pixel in an array, but a 128 x 64 byte array is too big for the dynamic memory.

Comment: Yes, 128 × 64 = 8 K, which is the whole RAM of the Mega. Seems you found yourself the answer to your question.

Comment: @EdgarBonet, mmm, looks like it, then I'll try to stick to the most basic variables (in a global scope) when memory usage is critical. But the readability's gonna suck :(

Comment: The question is one of time vs. space.  If time is more important then use up memory to hold the values.  If memory is more important then you use some time to recalculate things each time.  Only you really know what your project does and what its needs are.  There simply is not one right answer to this question.

Comment: On your collision issue: You might have to think of another algorithm, that works with less RAM but caches results. -- That is what I find satisfactory in embedded control: The need to *think* instead of mindlessly using a lot of resources.